# How to create a valid date in JavaScript running in FireFox?

Tags: date, firefox

I have following JavaScript function

```
var myDate=new Date("1" + "Nov 2013")
```

It works with IE, it returns Fri Nov 1 00:00:00 EDT 2013. But got invalid date with FireFox. How to fix my code so that it would work on both?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Date constructor with individual fields:

```
 var myDate = new Date(2013, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0); // Month is 0-11
```

Instead of the string parse.

Answer (score 0):

Add a space bewteen the day number and the month.

Really, though, if you can avoid parsing a string like the answer above suggests, that would be better:

new Date(2013, 10, 1);  // you can omit trailing zeros

Or, if you need to parse a string format, consider using ISO format, since it is likely the most interoperable:

new Date(Date.parse('2013-11-01')) // yyyy-mm-dd. Needs 2 digits for days